# My "Guess the password" is not working, how to fix it?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  char* attempt;
  char* password="buddy";

do
 {

  printf("Type a password:\n");
  scanf("%s", attempt);

if (attempt==password){

printf("You got it!\n");}
}

while (attempt!=password);
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate space for the string… try `char attempt[512];`.

Also, `attempt!=password` doesn't do what you think… use `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 0):

`attempt==password` is not working because these are different pointer value which have an address of memory.

Use strcmp function.

```
if (strcmp(attempt,password)==0){
```